# CakePHP - add/edit an item using multi-selection linking from multiple tables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

**Question Overview:**

I want to be able to edit an item (a restaurant in this case) and allow the user to select multiple options (cuisines) that use a table of connections to access a list of the options/cuisines.

**Question Details:**

I have 3 tables:

```
restaurants:          id, name, address, phone...etc
cuisines:             id, name, url_name
cuisine_connections:  id, restaurant_id, cuisine_id
```

As you can imagine, the cuisine_connections table is a list of connections between the cuisines, and the restaurants.  (If anyone has a better solution for this I'm all ears).

model/restaurant.php:

```
    var $hasMany = array(
    'CuisineConnection' => array(
        'className' => 'CuisineConnection',
        'foreignKey' => 'restaurant_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

model/cuisine.php

```
    var $hasMany = array(
    'CuisineConnection' => array(
        'className' => 'CuisineConnection',
        'foreignKey' => 'cuisine_id'
    )
);
```

model/cuisine_connection.php

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Cuisine' => array(
        'className' => 'Cuisine',
        'foreignKey' => 'restaurant_id',
        'dependent' => false
    ),
    'Restaurant' => array(
        'className' => 'Restaurant',
        'foreignKey' => 'restaurant_id'
    )
);
```

**I've tried this so far:**

controllers/restaurants_controller.php:

```
$this->set('cuisines', $this->Restaurant->CuisineConnection->Cuisine->find('list'));
```

admin_add.ctp:

```
echo $this->Form->input('cuisine_id', array('multiple'=>'checkbox'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read [this tutorial](http://www.packtpub.com/article/working-with-complex-associations-using-cakephp) for undestand clearly about implementing many-to-many association in CakePhp.  Beside that, the line code:

```
$this->set('cuisines', $this->Restaurant->CuisineConnection->Cuisine->find('list'));
```

has problems. I think that, depend on your description, you should list all the Cuisine for choosing with coresponding restaurant. The code should be replaced by:

```
$this->set('cuisines', $this->Cuisine->find('all'));
```

Comment: Marked as the answer for the link to that AWESOME tutorial.  It's a bit old, as it references ->generateList() instead of ->find('list'), but - it led me through the whole thing and helped me understand it better too! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you are looking for http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

also note the conventions for cake would be cuisines_restaurants, not cuisine_connections

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the convention thing - I appreciate the help.  Your link is on target too, but I'd already read it and still didn't understand.